# Tries to understand Tensorflow input_shape

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I have some confusions regarding to Tensorflow input_shape.

Suppose there are 3 documents (each row) in "doc" defined below, and the vocabulary has 4 words (each sublist in each row).

Further suppose that each word is represented by 2 numbers via word embedding.

The program only works when I specify input_shape=(3,4,2) under a Dense layer.
But when I use a LSTM layer, the program only works when input_shape=(4,2) but not when input_shape=(3,4,2).

So how to specify the input shape for such inputs? How to make sense of it?

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

doc=[
      [[1,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
      [[0,0],[1,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
      [[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[0,0]]
      ]

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(3,4,2))) # model.add(LSTM(2,input_shape=(4,2)))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=("accuracy"))
model.summary()
output=model.predict(doc)
print(model.weights)
print(output)
```

Comment: Is it because LSTM feed the 4 words in a document one at a time? So it cannot feed all 3 documents simutaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input_shape` argument in a `keras.layers.LTSM` layer expects a 2D array with a shape of `[timesteps, features]`. Your `doc` has the shape `[batch_size, timesteps, features]` and therefore one dimension too much.

You can use the `batch_input_shape` argument instead, if you want feed `batch_size`, too.

To do so, you have just to replace this line of your code:

```
model.add(LSTM(2,input_shape=(4,2)))
```

With this one:

```
model.add(LSTM(2,batch_input_shape=(3,4,2)))
```

If you're setting a specific `batch_size` in your model and then feed a different size other than 3 (in your case), you will get an error. Using `input_shape` instead you have the flexibility to feed any batch size to the network.